# Unable to resolve dependencies. 'xxx' is not compatible with 'yyy constraint: zzz)'

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017

We have a project that is utilizing a set of Nuget-based Azure libraries.  One of them was published with a specific MIN and MAX dependency on Newtonsoft.Json (max version being 7)

This was a headache, because other libraries depend on 8+ version of Netwon and this specific Azure library is just fine working with any modern Json package.

In VS2013, we forced to install this Azure library with newer version of Json package thru nuget installer and subsequently, Nuget never gave us any issues installing/updating other libraries.

However, after upgrading to VS2017, we cannot update any package (or at least the ones that depend on Json) and we get the error below.

**Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Newtonsoft.Json 8.0.3' is not compatible with 'Microsoft.Azure.Insights 0.15.0-preview constraint: Newtonsoft.Json (>= 6.0.8 && < 7.0.0)'**

How do we have Nuget ignore that specific Azure library's unimportant MAX version dependence?

Answer (score 5):

> How do we have Nuget ignore that specific Azure library's unimportant MAX version dependence?

If you confirm that Azure library is just fine working with any modern Json package and you want use the `Microsoft.Azure.Insights 0.15.0-preview` and 8+ version of `Newtonsoft.Json` at the same time. I would like provide a workaround to you, hope this can help you.

**Detailed Steps:**

1. Install the package `Microsoft.Azure.Insights 0.15.0-preview` with its dependencies first.
2. Only uninstall the package `Microsoft.Azure.Insights 0.15.0-preview`, Keep dependencies installed.
3. Update the `Newtonsoft.Json` to the version 8+.
4. Install the package `Microsoft.Azure.Insights 0.15.0-preview` **in the Package Manager Console with following NuGet command**:

`Install-package Microsoft.Azure.Insights -IncludePrerelease -IgnoreDependencies`

With the option `-IgnoreDependencies`, NuGet will ignore that specific Azure library's unimportant MAX version dependence:

[image]

Note: Need to mention is that if you update the `Newtonsoft.Json` package next time, you still need to follow the steps above to upgrade your `Newtonsoft.Json` package.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  As mentioned, I did do this originally, but now I cannot update any /other/ package that depends on Json, as Nuget is highlighting the conflict between Insights and Json

Comment: @Igorek, yes, as mentioned in my Note in the answer. If you update the Newtonsoft.Json package next time, you still have to uninstall package `Microsoft.Azure.Insights`, then update Json package, reinstall `Microsoft.Azure.Insights` with option `-IgnoreDependencies`. This is design by nuget.

Comment: Again, since you said "specific Azure library is just fine working with any modern Json package", so why not update the Json package to the latest version? In this case, you do not need to update it later.

Comment: This works once as the post says. But surely this is not a solution Nuget remains unusable. There must be a better way to reference a dependent package but override the transitive dependency constraints that does not require uninstalling. It leaves Nuget effectively broken.